# Asymptotic formula for Ricci flat metric

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, calabi-yau

Let $(\mathcal X,\mathcal D)\to T$ be a surjective holomorphic fibre space of K\"ahler manifolds of pairs such that fibers $(X_s,D_s)$ admit Ricci flat metric in bounded geometric sense (conic, Poincare singularities),i.e $Ric(\omega_s)=[D_s]$

Then, is there any asymptotic formula for $Ric(\omega_s)$ and $\omega_s$ when $s\to 0$?

Comment: I think you should explain better your situation. What do you mean exactly that the pair has a Ricci flat metric ? Do you want a flat metric on the complement of the boundary divisor? With which behaviour near the boundary? Which kind of singularities are admitted in the central fiber?

Comment: @diverietti , what do you mean central fibre?

Comment: $s=0$, I guess.

Comment: without condition

Comment: don't misunderstand, but I really think you should explain better and motivate more your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each fiber $(X_s,D_s)$ , if you kindly assume $D_s$ is snc with conic singularities such that $K_{X_s}+D_s$ is trivial, then $Ric(\omega_s)=[D_s]$ where $[D_s]$ is the current of integration of divisor $D_s$. Hence you need to know the asymptotic formula of current of integration $[D_s]$. See page 150 , 3rd line,

*D.Barlet , Dévelopment asymptotique des fonctions obtenues par intégration sur les fibres, Inventiones mathematicae (1982) Volume: 68, page 129-174.*

there is an asymptotic formula, hence you get an asymptotic formula when $s$ approaches to zero, some people from Stanford published a paper in Annals of math in 2016 as same as this formula of Barlet  about asymptotic formula of Ricci flat metric on pair $(X,D)$ (Kähler–Einstein metrics with edge singularities, Annals of Mathematics,
Pages 95-176 from Volume 183 (2016), Issue 1 by Thalia Jeffres, Rafe Mazzeo, Yanir A. Rubinstein).

The important point is that, Ricci flat metric is a good metric in the sense of Mumford and if you don't assume such a mild singularities on central fiber in the sense of MMP, you loose goodness of such metric on central fiber.

**Good metric in the sense of Mumford**

Let $\omega$ be a smooth local $p$-form defined on $V_\alpha$ we say
$\omega$ has Poincaré growth if there is a constant
$C_\alpha>0$ depending on $\omega$ such that

$$|\omega(t_1,t_2,...,t_p)|^2\leq C_\alpha \prod_{i=1}^p||t_i||^2$$
for any point
$z
\in V_\alpha$
and $t_1,...,t_p\in T_zX$ where $||.||$ is taken on Poincaré metric. We say $\omega$
is Mumford metric if both
$\omega$ and $d\omega$ have Poincaré growth.

Comment: Is there English version of this paper?

Comment: I don't know, maybe.

Comment: Probably not. You could look for citations of the paper (say, on Google Scholar) and see if someone else has written in English about the same or similar results. Also, if you want to work in this area, I recommend learning how to read French. It's not that hard.